# Frame transition in sony vegas

Tags: video-editor, animation, vegas-pro, transitions

Can someone help, by telling me can this transition, where frame is pushed up multiple repeatings, be made in Sony Vegas, and how?

[Transition Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B41WH7tEn_XwcjVYZ2lBT3c2czA)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the effect used for both the zoom in the beginning and the multiple vertical frames later on is the effect `'BlurMoCurves'`. It's part of Sapphire OFX plugins and can be installed (and used) in Sony Vegas Pro. It's not a transition but thanks to zooming it can look like one.

The very last frames, when the clip goes down vertically, is probably one of `Roll` transitions which are a part of NewBlueFX plugins, also compatible with Sony Vegas. [Here](https://www.newbluefx.com/products/transitions/flow/) you can see the examples (the one I'd say was used is the second one in the `Roll` video). Hope this helps!